# Repetitive table in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to make a repetitive table in `Tikz`, but couldn't find any examples for how to do this.  Here's how I wish my table would look like in `Tikz`:

[image]

I tried firing up some standard table templates but nothing compares with the `tikz` graphics that I'm used to.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this in TiKZ?

Comment: In any case, please post an example showing what you've tried which people can use as a starting point. Just posting an image and expecting people to create it from scratch in order to help you is somewhat inconsiderate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "repetitive," I am taking that literally.  Here I make a copy of the "unit table" with `tabular`, save it in a box, and then stack it as needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newsavebox\tabcell
\def\utc{\usebox{\tabcell}}
\begin{document}
\savebox\tabcell{%
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}\\\hline
x~~~~~~ & name1\\\hline
y & name2\\\hline
z & name3\\\hline
w & name4\\\hline
k & name5\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\Shortstack{
\utc\utc\utc\\
\utc\utc\utc
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if the units are not actually repetitive (see OP comment below), then perhaps a straight `tabular` array is sufficient for your needs (no stack required!).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|c|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}&
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}\\\hline
x~~~~~~ & name1&x~~~~~~ & name1&x~~~~~~ & name1\\\hline
y & name2&y & name2&y & name2\\\hline
z & name3&z & name3&z & name3\\\hline
w & name4&w & name4&w & name4\\\hline
k & name5&k & name5&k & name5\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}&
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Name}\\\hline
x~~~~~~ & name1&x~~~~~~ & name1&x~~~~~~ & name1\\\hline
A & name32&E & name12&y & name22\\\hline
B & name33&F & name13&z & name23\\\hline
C & name34&G & name14&w & name24\\\hline
D & name35&H & name15&k & name25\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To meet the question desiderata, you could do `\tikz{\node {...};}` around it, I guess ;).

Comment: @cfr `8^)` If your only tool is `tikz`, then all problems start looking like graphs.

Comment: `8^)`? New one to me...

Comment: @warship Are some of them repetitive, or none at all?

Comment: In the code above I get the error: `File stackengine.sty not found`

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Some yes, but not all... the best would be to generate each one individually from scratch, if that is possible.

Comment: @warship Download the `.sty` and `.pdf` files from http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  Place the .sty file in your working directory and it should compile.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can you advise on how to wrap a `tabular` into a figure?  For some reason, the classic `begin{figure}` style doesn't work..

Comment: @warship As long as it fits on one page (which is what a `tabular` and `figure` can handle), then `\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\caption{...}\end{figure}` should work.  You can use `[htbp]` optional parameters on `figure` to suggest to LaTeX the desired placement of the figure (here, top, bottom, page).

Answer (score 3):

A standard `tabular` (with `array` enhancements) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mytable}[1][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.8cm}|c}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name} \\ \hline
    x & name1 \\ \hline
    y & name2 \\ \hline
    z & name3 \\ \hline
    w & name4 \\ \hline
    k & name5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{*3{@{}|@{}c}@{}|}
  \hline
  \mytable & \mytable & \mytable \\
  \mytable & \mytable & \mytable \\
  \mytable & \mytable & \mytable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the table turns out to be less repetitive than the question title suggests, the exact same approach may still be used. Just use the required content instead of repeating the one nested `tabular` command.

Comment: The warship giveth the tick and the warship taketh away the tick. :-)

Comment: Wish I could tick both, preferably at the same time :)